# Getting type error while Implementing hereMap Api

Tags: angular7, here-api

I'm trying to add maps via hereMaps Api in my webApplication which is in Angular7 .While creating platform using service module which is

```
this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
          "app_id": "{9qrlA6ZVcLPDw16Mkclk}",
      });
```

I'm getting following saying ,

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined
```

i have installed npm here-js-api package and also declared service module

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

in src/index.html .but still i'm getting the same type error.!

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Add your script file to your angular.json in the script section

```
"scripts": [
  ...
  "./node_modules/heremap/dist/heremap.min.js",
  "./node_modules/heremap/dist/libhere.min.js",
]
```

Then styles in syle section

```
"styles": [
  ...
  "./node_modules/heremap/css/heremap.css",
]
```

Now you have to declare Heremap from window and then use it:

```js
declare const hm = window.heremap;

export class YourService {
  // Now you can use hm
  // eg.
  hm.config({
    app_id: APP_ID,
    app_code: APP_CODE,
  }); 
  hm.getAvailableMapStyle().then(style => {
    console.log("Style ", style);
  });

  // show map fragment
  // to see console message, open debugger window
  hm.map(
    "map", {
      zoom: 6,
      scheme:"satellite.day",
      viewChange: (zoom, coord) => {
        console.log("viewchange", zoom, coord)
      },
      click: (coord, button, key) => {
        console.log("click", coord, button, key)
      },
      keydown: (key) => {
        console.log("key down", key)
      }
    }
  );
}
```